# Double linked list in c++ with inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, josephus

I try to solve Jopsephus problem and i need a circular double linked list, but i do not know how to do the following thing:
I got these classes:

```
class node
{
private:
    int info;
    nod *next;
}


class double_nod: public node
{
private:
    nod *previous;}

class List
{
private:
    double_node* first_node;
    double_node* current_node;
    int length;}
```

I am trying to do a function that return the next double_node from the list but I get an error in the function below because node cannot be converted to double_node :

```
void List::get_next_node()
{
    if(current_node->get_urm()!=NULL) // get_urm() is from class node and return next
    {
        current_node=current_node->get_urm();
    }
}
```

Any ideea? I got a homework to do and OOP is way too hard for me at the beginning.

Comment: You can use `static_cast`. If you want some runtime type checking, you can use `dynamic_cast`. but you would need to make the destructor virtual in the base class (you should do that anyway).

Comment: Side note: This is a bad idea. The logic for inserting, removing and iterating single and doubly linked lists is very different. they simply do not behave the same, so using `double_nod` in a context where a `node` is expected could end in tears, frustration, and totally unnecessary debugging and you gain almost nothing in return. Make doubly linked lists and singly linked lists each with their own distinct node structure.

Comment: I have some task to do, it is not my choice this way . I have to create a node class and a double_nod class that inherits node and after that to create a lost with double node ellements